# Does this joint independence hold?

Tags: probability

Suppose for random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$ we have $X_1$ is independent with $X_2$ given $X_4$, $X_1$ is independent with $X_3$ given $X_4$. Does that imply that $X_1$ is independent with $(X_2,X_3)$ given $X_4$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by e.g. "$X_1$ is independent with $X_2$ given $X_4$". I know what independence of rv's means, and also independence of rv's given some event. But I am not familiar with independence of rv's given some rv.